# Getting a file name, followed by Write-Host (PowerShell 5.1)

Tags: powershell

I'm sure this has probably been answered before but Google-fu seems incapable of locating what I'm looking for.

I'm attempting to write a script which will take a user input for a file name (a FQDN). Then, it will check if that name contains a phrase ("Printer Inventory"). If so, then Write-Host "Success" and if not Write-Host "Not formatted" - specifically I'm setting the script to look for the string "Printer Inventory".

It doesn't seem to matter what I set the file name as at my Read-Host, I can't get the script to understand the file name as a string (at least I think that's my problem).

So far, it looks like this (sanitized & simplified).

```
$input = Read-Host "Enter File name"
if($input.name -contains "*Printer Inventory*") {
   Write-Host "Success"
   Read-Host "Press Enter"
}else {
   Write-Host "Not formatted correctly"
   Read-Host "Press enter"
}
```

The $input variable would be formatted something similar to the below:
"\netshare\usershare\user\04-22-2022 Building 7 Printer Inventory.txt"

(formatted this way because the user will be doing a shift-click to run the "Copy as path" to get the file name; date, building ID will change over time)

I can change "-contains" to "-like" "-matches" "-eq" - anything I could think of and my else statement always outputs "Not formatted"
I've changed "$input.name" to just "$input" and tried

```
if ($_.name ...)
```

and used

```
$input.FullName
```

or

```
$_.FullName
```

Thank you, anyone, for your help.

Errata: just a little context, but not specifically pertinent to my request -
I'm actually going to manipulate the data within the file, which I've got working without an "if" statement. However, I want to get this working so that if the user accidentally provides the wrong file the script terminates before processing the file. I left those portions of the script out because I really just want to focus on getting the name recognition working.

Comment: Why ask the user to type in a file, vs having them select from a list? Just use the Out-GridView cmdlet, to provide the selection list and process that selection.  see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-out-gridview-selection-works-in-powershell. BTW, Writing to the console is the PowerShell default. As such no real need to Write-Host except in needed circumstances; like color, extra formatting, etc. This Write-Host "Not formatted correctly" and this "Not formatted correctly", goes to the screen.

Comment: [1] the `-contains` operator is an _array/collection_ operator. your object is likely a string at the point you are testing. [*grin*] try `-like` [a wildcard operator] or  `.Contains()` [a string method]. ///// [2] the dotnet stuff has a built in file picker - and you can give it a pattern to use. take a look at >>> Hey, Scripting Guy! Can I Open a File Dialog Box with Windows PowerShell? - Scripting Blog — https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-open-a-file-dialog-box-with-windows-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. Properties like `.Name` or `.Size` *aren't* automagically added to strings that seem to contain paths. They're only found on [System.IO.FileSystemInfo objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=net-6.0), which aren't strings at all – they're custom data types that just masquerade as strings sometimes.

One way to create a FileSystemInfo object is to call `Get-Item` on the string path:

```
$path = "\\netshare\whatever"

$item = Get-Item $path

echo $item.Name
echo $item.FullName

echo $item.GetType()     # reveals the object's real type

echo "$item"             # uses .ToString() to stringify the object
```